# What's Wrong with My C++ Code is Wrong on CodeForces?

Tags: c++

[image]

```html
#include <iostream>
#include<math.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int h1,min1,h2,min2;
cin>>h1>>min1>>h2>>min2;
if(h1==h2 && min1>min2)
    cout<<(24*60)-fabs(min1-min2);
    else if (h1>h2)
        cout<<((fabs((h1-24)+fabs(h2%12))*60))-fabs(min1-min2);
    else if (h2>h1)
        cout<<((h2-h1)*60)-fabs(min1-min2);
}
```

all the outPut is right but it says wrong in code forces I want to know what's wrong is it just CodeForces or there's something unlogic or the Code is wrong in general !?

Comment: You should read [this excellent post by Eric Lippert](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) about debugging small programs such as yours, and apply the techniques described there.

Comment: That's a good question: what *is* wrong with your code?  Maybe if you explained what the problem was, someone could help you solve it.

Comment: I did But I don't know why it didn't appear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio saying, what wrong :

```
    1>------ Build started: Project: test19, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  test19.cpp
1>c:\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\test19\test19\test19.cpp(15): error C2668: 'fabs' : ambiguous call to overloaded function
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\math.h(565): could be 'long double fabs(long double)'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\math.h(517): or       'float fabs(float)'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\math.h(118): or       'double fabs(double)'
1>          while trying to match the argument list '(int)'
1>c:\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\test19\test19\test19.cpp(17): error C2668: 'fabs' : ambiguous call to overloaded function
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\math.h(565): could be 'long double fabs(long double)'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\math.h(517): or       'float fabs(float)'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\math.h(118): or       'double fabs(double)'
1>          while trying to match the argument list '(int)'
1>c:\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\test19\test19\test19.cpp(17): error C2668: 'fabs' : ambiguous call to overloaded function
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\math.h(565): could be 'long double fabs(long double)'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\math.h(517): or       'float fabs(float)'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\math.h(118): or       'double fabs(double)'
1>          while trying to match the argument list '(int)'
1>c:\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\test19\test19\test19.cpp(19): error C2668: 'fabs' : ambiguous call to overloaded function
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\math.h(565): could be 'long double fabs(long double)'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\math.h(517): or       'float fabs(float)'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\math.h(118): or       'double fabs(double)'
1>          while trying to match the argument list '(int)'
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Will you explain in a simple way please :D

Comment: this mean, that there is more than one decision for argument list of fabs, and compiler dont know what to choose. Right will be fabs(double(<expression>)) for example. But because we have all arguments int, you must use just abs() instead fabs